# Angular JS Wbpage reload issue

Tags: angularjs, web-applications, html, reload

I am developing a SPA web app using Angular JS,html5. It's working fine when I login and seeing all page in it, When I am trying to reload web page its nothing was showing except header and footer and page not refreshing n even not going to back too. Why any one can suggest where is the problem?

Comment: I think you are at least going to have to show us your routes so we can see if anything obvious jumps out.

Comment: seems that your page should be in error